# Draw matching 1:1 real life lengths on both screen and printing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, printing, drawing

I wonder what the best approach would be create a drawing with dimensions matching 1:1 with reality. What I mean is that if I draw two lines at a distance of 1 inch from each other, then you could take a ruler and measure exactly 1 inch on the screen where you display them, and/or the printer where you print the drawing.

I'm trying specifically to do this in iOS, and keep it device independent so that the drawing will always match 1:1 whether if displayed on a iPod or iPad and so on.

So far the only solution I came up just takes in account the diagonal resolution of each device (163ppi diagonal on iPod and 132ppi diagonal on iPad), but a test drawing 10 lines spaced at 1 inch from each other reveals that on the iPad screen 1 inch is a little it short then the real life one.

ideas or suggestions are greatly welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to detect the device, then know the device's PPI (pixels per inch). Then create your artwork to match.